# Laravel: how to communicate between client & server with ISO8601, but store in standard date format, with minimal project modifications?

Tags: php, angular, laravel

By default, Laravel will cast/serialize/access/mutate dates as "Standard date format", also known as `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`. This is fine, it works well for interacting with MySQL, as it's—I believe—the standard data storage format for the `DATETYPE` column type.

However, my client is built using Angular, which often expects dates to be parsed as ISO8601, and in fact, the built in `date` and corresponding `formatDate` pipes Angular provides don't work out of the box with "Standard date formats" that Laravel expects at all. JavaScript's built in `Date` object also serialises better to ISO8601 than Laravel's preferred date format.

From this, it appears the quickest solution to this is to force Laravel to send all dates as ISO8601 from the API, process all received dates as ISO8601 back to `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` and internally store them in my database as its preferred format.

Where I'm getting stuck is on how I can achieve this with **minimal modifications** to my Laravel project, from a vanilla installation. I'm not after a solution which requires implementing [multiple mutators/accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the dozens of different dates on the dozens of different models I have.

There's also a huge number of different date manipulation options that Laravel provides, that I frankly can't get working in the correct order. Off the top of my head, there's:

- [Model Accessors/Model Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).
- [Date Serialization in `AppServiceProvider`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization)
- [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)
- [`$protected $dateFormat`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)
- [Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

What modifications do I need to make to my Laravel project to enable the outcome I'm looking for?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a bit about 5.8 automatically serializing to an 8601 string.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to apply a filter to the dates on the angular side

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* of your dates to be 8601 strings, then your best bet is the `AppServiceProvider.php` solution you linked, and instead of returning `$carbon->format('U')` return `$carbon->toIso8601String();`. Note that this only works when serializing to JSON, if you'd like to change the default format when casting to a string then you'd need to add `Carbon::setToStringFormat(Carbon::ISO8601);` to the provider as well.

As of Laravel 5.8, the `Illuminate\Support\Carbon` object defaults to 8601 when being serialized:

```
➜  test58 php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.3
➜  test58 php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.2 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> json_encode(now())
=> ""2019-03-05T20:32:27.332943Z""
>>>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. The `setToStringFormat` indeed works to send data to the client, but this doesn't solve my issue of also wanting dates to be mutated from ISO8601 format back into Carbon instances when my client submits data to Laravel.

Comment: Are you saying you want `$request->input('some_date')` to automatically be converted into a Carbon instance? Or do you mean just when you pull it from the database? The `$dates` array takes care of the latter, the former would only be solved with some custom code.